# How to create perfect overlapping scales on awkwardly shaped meshes

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, sculpting, displacement, 3d-printing

I have several projects that require a seamless overlay of sculpted scales, like a snake or a shark, the end goal of having them 3D printed, where the scales stay in line across the entire body.  What would be the best way to approach this, ive tried sculpting with a texture using tiled and space, but that doesnt allow for seamless transitions across the entire mesh.  Also geomentry nodes and displace modifier, but got undesirable results.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing image box mapping inside geometry nodes, there still gonna be seam but it will be blended.

[image]

[image]

Comment: question, it seems I dont have some of the nodes you use, like box mapping and scale, how did you set this up?

Comment: I attached Box mapping node group blend file to the to my answer, it's custom node group, for scale it's Vector Math node set to Scale

Comment: This looks great. Just a sketch of the strategy you adopted _inside_ the Box-Mapping group would really improve your answer, though. As it stands, it's not really self-contained.. it amounts to a link to your group. I know it's a pain to illustrate huge GN trees :( .. but a summary of your approach would do.

Comment: Yes, @Higgsas could you add a short description of how the node group works, maybe a screenshot of the contents and logic behind it.

Comment: @TomHoefken Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).